# Can you detect when user starts/stops navigating with OrbitControl?

Tags: three.js

I'm looking to hide some elements in the scene while the user is navigating. Is there a way to detect when a user starts rotating / panning / zooming with `THREE.OrbitControls` and also when they have stopped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look very well documented but there are `start`, `change`, and `end` events that you can subscribe to.

You can see them defined in the source [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js#L249) and see them fired with [dispatchEvent](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js#L729). Here's how you would use them:

```
controls.addEventListener('start', () => console.log('started dragging!'));

controls.addEventListener('change', () => console.log('dragged!'));

controls.addEventListener('end', () => console.log('stopped dragging!'));
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you appreciate the help!